# .txt file data into 2 column csv file batch file

Tags: csv, input, batch-file

Hopefully this is a simple answer. Basically I would like to be able to get the contents of a multiline text file that we will call FileSample.txt. It may contain something along the lines of

```
Some text sample1 : Extra1  
Some text sample2 : Extra2        
Some text sample3 : Extra3  
Some text sample4 : Extra4
```

and essentially enter it into a 2-column csv we will call Output.csv. First column should be the filename and the second column should have the contents (including hard returns) of the text file. So essentially the csv should contain this...

```
FileName,Contents  
FileSample.txt,"Some text sample1 : Extra1 Some text sample2 : Extra2 Some text sample3 : Extra3  Some text sample4 : Extra4"
```

I apologize for the utter confusion here, and the totally noob scripting skills. I am really trying to get this done so I made a solution with powershell.

```
$Content = Get-Content .\FileSample.txt 
$FileName = Get-ChildItem .\FileSample.txt

New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    FileName  = $FileName.Name
    Content = "$Content"
} | Export-Csv .\Output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

*As much as I did not want to deviate from my initial request of getting this done via a batch file I did manage to get the same results out of this vbscript below without having to resort to using a file saved from ExifTool.*

```
Dim WshShell, oExec
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("%comspec% /c ""D:\EXIFTOOL\exiftool.exe"" test.jpg")
x1 = oExec.StdOut.ReadAll
x2 = Replace(x1, chr(34), chr(34) & chr(34))

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objLogFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("D:\EXIFTOOL\Output.csv", 1, False)

objLogFile.Write "Filename,"
objLogFile.Write "ExifData"
objLogFile.Writeline
objLogFile.Write chr(34) & "sample6.csv" & chr(34) & ","
objLogFile.Write chr(34) & x2 & chr(34)
objLogFile.Writeline
objLogFile.Close
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. In addition, please take the time to share the steps you've taken so far to research or resolve things on your own.

Comment: Sure I'll post back shortly

Comment: Your proposed output is not a valid CSV format. It is possible to have multi-line values, but the value must be enclosed in quotes, and any internal quotes must be escaped (I think doubled). Many programs that claim to read CSV format do not properly handle multi-line values.

Comment: What is the `¶` character? If it represents an actual line feed in the content, then my prior comment still stands.

Comment: Yes you are right I need the Contents field to contain the Quotes and yes you are right double quotes does escape internal ones. the Pilcro symbol its just to show that it needs to contain multiple lines. I am running DirectoryMonitor to automatically export exif data using ExifTool for new images added to an externally stored container in FileMaker. The contents of that file will need to go into that Contents field

Comment: I'm trying to then import that csv automatically into a table in FileMaker where I will later parse for specific exif data.

Comment: I can't understand: you will remove the line breaks and later on add the same line breaks to the file? In my eyes, that makes no sense.

Comment: Not quite captcha. I just want to be stress that the source text file will have multiple lines and that I need it like that as well in the csv file's Content column. I can open the text file, Select All, and then paste into 1 cell in Excel. I notice that it keeps the carriage returns in Excel. When opening in WordPad, I see that Excel enclosed the entire field in quotes and doublequoted any internal ones. I'm sorry if I confused you. I am looking into ExifTool to see if it is possible to do this without having to resort to a batch file

Comment: Until now it is not clear, what you precisely need. Your question is **not** constructive and should be closed.

Comment: Endoro I'm sorry for my lack of clarity. I just updated my question with a very rudimentary powershell script. It gives me the result I was looking for but if only i can get this in a batch script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

@ECHO FileName,Contents

SET FILE=FileSample.txt

SET FIRST=^"%FILE%^",^"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%l IN (%FILE%) DO @((SET LINE=%%l) & (@ECHO !FIRST!!LINE:^"=^"^"!) & (SET FIRST=))
@ECHO ^"
```

This echoes the filename, a comma, a double quote, then every line of the file (with double quotes "escaped" by replacing them with a double-double quote—which is necessary if the data in the file may have double quotes in it), followed by a (closing) double quote.

The one limitation I see is that if the file doesn't end with a newline, the closing double quote will effectively add one. If the file does end with a newline, the FOR loop won't process that empty line, and the output will be correct. Overcoming that limitation would probably mean manually counting the lines (an additional loop iterating over the lines) and adding an extra variable and check in the FOR loop. It's too messy for me to think about unless you really, *really* want that behavior. (At some point, the burden of doing something in batch/CMD becomes worse than depending on PowerShell, VBScript, or some other real programming language to get *simple* things done.)

If you intended to process numerous files, you could put the last three lines in a "subroutine" (my preference over creating nested FOR loops) and CALL it within a FOR loop that iterates over the files in question.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

@ECHO FileName,Contents

FOR %%f IN (FileSample*.txt) DO CALL :PROCESS_FILE "%%~f"

GOTO :EOF

:PROCESS_FILE
SET "FILE=%~1"

SET FIRST=^"%FILE%^",^"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%l IN (%FILE%) DO @((SET LINE=%%l) & (@ECHO !FIRST!!LINE:^"=^"^"!) & (SET FIRST=))
@ECHO ^"
EXIT /B
```

The extra quoting of arguments to :PROCESS_FILE is to handle the case when the file name has a space in it. If it contains a space and you don't quote it, the pieces of the file name will be treated like separate arguments. I suppose you could use %* in that case, but I prefer to quote things to make it clear that I want the data treated as a single unit.

Comment: JubJub thank you this works as intended. The added line at the end of the output should not be a problem. This works as intended and appreciate your efforts and your understanding of my question to begin with. I agree with you about using a different language for this. I initially needed to use a batch script because DirectoryMonitor can only autoexecute from .exe,.bat, and .com files. Your solution worked for me great. I will be using it after i figure how I can use the output for exiftool directly in this batch file, without resorting to the text file similar to how i got it in the vbscript